# What popular thing does this text represent?

Tags: riddle

As my first riddle, good luck finding what hides behind that text!

The man thinks it's silver
All he's selling is his old dirty cave
A wednesday afternoon
he tries and he tries but get none
Times flies
he stands there in darkness
We all see this stranger
dark shriveled shape

What does this text represent?
The answer should not be vague or ambiguous, if you find it you'll know!

Hint 1 (small hint)

> At the end he's selling his old dirty cave

Hint 2 (bigger hint)

> it is a song

Hint 3 ( queen of all hints)

> ZoSo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to tentatively guess that the clues are

> an inversion (of sorts) of the lyrics of *Stairway to Heaven*. This is mostly based on Hint 3, but I'm taking my shot, in the spirit of Eminem in the movie *8 Mile*

The **man** **thinks** it's **silver**

> There's a **lady** who's **sure** all that glitters is **gold**

All he's **selling** is his old dirty **cave**

> She's **buying** a **stairway to heaven** (I'm not thrilled about this one, but "cave" sort of indicates down/into the earth and "stairway to heaven", well)

A wednesday afternoon

> not a clue on this one, honestly, unless the idea is that stores aren't closed on a Wednesday afternoon

**he tries and he tries but get none**

> **With a word she can get what she came for**

he stands there in **darkness**
We all see this **stranger**

> There walks a lady **we all know**
>  Who **shines white light** and wants to show

Comment: You got it allright mate! good job :)